# Creating a new array containing true copies of the elements of another array multiple times via Google Script

Tags: arrays, google-apps-script

I'm having some trouble creating a new array which repeats multiple elements of another array multiple times via Google Apps Script.

For example, the array I'm beginning with is the following:

```
var sourceArray = [
                   [['A', 1], ['B', 1]]
                  ]
```

I would like to be able to create a new array which repeats the elements that array an X number of times. Say if I want to repeat those elements 3 times, I'll get the following new array as a result:

```
var newArray = [
                [['A', 1], ['B', 1]],
                [['A', 1], ['B', 1]],
                [['A', 1], ['B', 1]]
               ]
```

I was able to accomplish that by using the following function found here on StackOverFlow:

```
function mutateArray(arr,n){
  var temp = [];
  while(n--) Array.prototype.push.apply(temp,arr);
  return temp;
}
```

Once I ran that function like so, I got the "newArray" above as a result:

```
mutateArray(sourceArray,3);
```

However, although that function did create a new array containing the elements of sourceArray 3 times, I am now running into a problem: I can't seem to make changes to the elements of newArray individually. To illustrate, if I try to change the first `['A', 1]` to `['A', 2]` as follows...

```
newArray[0][0][1] = 2;
```

...that will change not only the first `['A', 1]`, but *all* of them.

From what I could gather, the problem is that when I created newArray, the method I used didn't create three different subarrays with the same values, but rather three references to the same array. So that is my question: how can I create, via Google Apps Script, a new array which repeats multiple elements of another array multiple times, making sure such new array contains *true copies* of (not only refereces to) the source array.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this. Could you provide the complete code that leads to this result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to make a deep copy of the (nested) array. As long as your arrays only contain primitive types (ie. strings, numbers, booleans) and/or object literals composed of primitive types, you should be able to `JSON.stringify()` the array and then `JSON.parse()` the array to make a deep copy of it.

Something like:

```js
var deepCopy = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(arr));
```

Then you can invoke the `apply` function with the `deepCopy` array instead of the `arr` variable.

Comment: Worked like a charm. Wonderful. :)